# Grails database migration plugin

Tags: grails

While reading about the database migration plugin in the book "The Definitive Guide To Grails 2", I came across a question. I understand this plugin is used to migrate an older schema to a newer one that the code base might be expecting to work with. Immediately, the one scenario I could think of why this might be necessary is that a code base expecting to work with a newer schema might try to access properties in domain classes that might not be there (null exceptions). I wanted to know if anyone can help me as to other reasons for migrating the schema so that I can better my thinking on this. Thank you.

Comment: You will migrate your database everytime you change your domain model and your application is the only place to define your reality.  The ideal scenario for this is, that you have a database running for your single grails app.  Once there is a new release of the app, it will update the db to the new specs automatically when booting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database Migration Grails plugin is a convenient way to update your database schema. It's not necessarily just to migrate to a completely different schema. The plugin is actually just a wrapper around Liquibase. It aims to integrate the database management into your codebase which makes it easily versioned and tracked with the rest of your code. It also allows for you to easily update your database in a controlled way (dbm-update on start). This works great for continuous deployments.